# Cant login to phpmyadmin "#2002 - No such file or directory" and " Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed"

Tags: server, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've tried to comment out

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
```

these two lines in my `config.inc.php` file.

I uncommented these lines:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '127.0.0.1';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '80';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
```

and put in 127.0.0.1 and port 80.

When I installed mysql i did `mysql_secure_installation` and set up a root user with all privliges (I can log into this user via commandline). So that shouldt be the problem, right?

I dont really know what to troubleshoot for. I've looked at all the other links with the same issue but none helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve it. Im not quite sure what caused the error in the first place. But I noticed that I couldnt log on to mysql via the terminal either. I got a `#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` error.
So what I did was that I created a new user

```
 create user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' identified by 'mypass';
```

But this gave me the error: `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'`

So I found a thread which said that we should "assume" that this user already exists. So what I did was:

```
mysql> drop user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> create user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' identified by 'mypass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
```

After this I could log into phpmyadmin with this user.